# Не работает Binding в сторону источника, если не определён ContentControl. Как исправить, не добавляя ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Я хочу переопределить шаблон для `TextBox` на такой:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="n" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Вот с чем я его применяю:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TicketAmountField" Template="{StaticResource CustomTextBox}" Padding="10, 3, 10, 3" Text="{Binding TicketAmount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="18" Foreground="#307CF6" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#92B8F6"/>
```

TextBox может только получить значение из привязанного свойства, а вот вызвать *setter* не может.

Я проверил: если заменить `<TextBox />` на `<ContentControl />` в шаблоне, то всё заработает. Но мне не нравиться, то что нет курсора при получении полем фокуса.

---

Как сделать так, чтобы и поле вело себя нормально (был курсор) и чтобы привязка работала в обе стороны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Border  CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Border>
```

Пиши вот так, и будет тебе счастье.